# What is the simplest way to prevent Error return In a GET request from an object in PHP

Tags: php, object

in my case
Suppose an $object is completely empty
And I ask him

```
object ->get_id
```

What's the shortest way a whip will return empty

Answer (score 2):

```
$id = isset($object) && isset($object->get_id) ? $object->get_id : null;
```

Comment: Thank you
Is this the shortest way?

Comment: If you don't know whether or not `$object` or `$object->get_id` is declared, it's the shortest way. If you know that `$object->get_id` is always declared when `$object` is declared, you can remove the `&& isset($object->get_id)` part.